# Cant update my Realm data base in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm

Im trying to update a Realm database in a current app.
but everytime i run the app its keep telling me to migrate the date base.

i have tried both the migration and the .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded() non seams to work.

keep getting the same error
Migration is required due to the following errors:

- Class 'NaturAbout' has been added.

  - Class 'NaturMap' has been added.
  - Class 'NaturMenu' has been added.
  - Property 'NaturEverything.map' has been added.
  - Property 'NaturEverything.menu' has been added.
  - Property 'NaturEverything.about' has been added.

protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

```
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .migration(new MyMigration())
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();

    Realm realm;
    realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.deleteAll();
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

}

public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

```
    RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

    if (oldVersion == 0) {
        schema.get("NaturEverything")
                .addField("map", NaturMap.class)
                .addField("menu", NaturMenu.class)
                .addField("about", NaturAbout.class);
        schema.create("NaturAbout")
                .addField("id", int.class)
                .addField("header", NaturLocalizedString.class)
                .addField("excerpt", NaturLocalizedString.class)
                .addField("description", NaturLocalizedString.class)
                .addField("image", NaturLocalizedString.class);
        schema.create("NaturMap")
                .addField("id", int.class)
                .addField("zoom", int.class)
                .addField("lat", int.class)
                .addField("lng", int.class);
        schema.create("NaturMenu")
                .addField("id", int.class)
                .addField("about", NaturLocalizedString.class)
                .addField("map", NaturLocalizedString.class)
                .addField("routes", NaturLocalizedString.class);
        oldVersion++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only solution i found was to delete the .realm file and then make it create a new. and i used a flag to handle that this only got call ones.